# Passing json object to model as payload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest, ruby-on-rails-5

Im having an issue on my rails app.
i'm letting Users submit and filled out bracket once they'r done editing it.
:

```
 <%= form_for Tournoi.new do |f| %>
  <button id="SaveButton" onclick="save()">Save</button>
<% end %>
```

Using XMLHttpRequest i send the json object to my db :

```
function save() {
    var data = {};
    var tojs = myDiagram.model.toJSON();
    data.payload = tojs;
    //var parsed_json = JSON.parse(data);
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    myDiagram.isModified = false;

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = callback;
    request.open("post", "http://localhost:3000/malesingle", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.send(json)
```

my migration is set up in a way that it accepts json object as payload :

```
class CreateTournois < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :tournois do |t|
      t.json 'payload'
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

my tournois controller is where i think im having some difficulties :

```
def create
     @tournoi = Tournoi.new params[:payload]
        if @tournoi.save
      redirect_to root_url
        flash[:success] = "Your tournament bracket has been validated!"
        redirect_to @tournoi
      else
        redirect_to malesingle_url
      end
  end
```

Here is the problem every time i try to submit the bracket, the content of my json object stringify appeared on my terminal, the POST argument seem to go through, my payload parameters becomes the content of my json object but for some reason i get a Argument Error (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.) which makes my migration roll back.

I know the error comes from my controller but i cant seem to find where i went wrong or if there is something missing or in the wrong order.

Comment: `params[:payload]` as seen by your Rails app is a regular string. You need to parse it into json before passing it to the `new` method: `Tournoi.new(JSON.parse(params[:payload])`

Comment: Also, I think you need to specify the field in your model: `Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload])`

Comment: @mikwat `def create @tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))`,  still gets me an error went from a ArgumentError to a TypeError no implicite conversion of nil into string

Answer (score 0):

Since your Rails endpoint expects form data, send your JSON like this:

```
var tojs = myDiagram.model.toJSON();
var json = JSON.stringify(tojs);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("payload", json);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("post", "http://localhost:3000/malesingle", true);
request.send(formData);
```

Then, assuming you're using Postgres which supports fields of type JSON, the "payload" param needs to be parsed into a hash and the field name needs to be specified:

```
Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))
```

Comment: The post method for my /malesingle path goes thru, the migration is launched now the post into my /tournois path gets me a TypeError and the migration rolls back

Comment: i tried `raise params.inspect` , to check the issue the only thing is a permitted: false

Comment: @DezzH I've updated my answer to include some javascript changes. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Adding the formdata into my script doesnt sort the issue i still get a TypeError(no implicit conversion of nil into string) in create line 8 which is `Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))
`. My json object is saved into my db but the TypeErro still comes up

Comment: I think that `params[:payload]` must still be `nil` for some reason... Can you verify via `puts params[:payload]`?

Comment: Also, make sure you DO NOT set the content-type (it will be set to multipart/form-data automatically by `FormData`).

Comment: Yea i params[:payload] is nil for some reason i dont know why, i submit into the db it is all saved but my browsers loads up TypeError on `@tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))` with a no implicit conversion of nil into String :/. yea i didnt set content-type coze of **FormData**

Comment: Can you use your browser's javascript console to determine what exactly it's posting to `http://localhost:3000/malesingle`?

Comment: its posting to the attributes payload my script json

Comment: Can you include a screenshot or similar of the javascript console in your question?

Comment: the feed from the javascript console is too fast for me to screenshot once i click on save, i just don't understand why i get a TypeError on my line 7 which `@tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))` while the content of my json object is inserted into payload

Comment: Since you're posting via ajax your javascript console shouldn't get cleared... that's a possible red flag for me.

Comment: what does **Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.** means? just pops up on my controller, after submiting